# What algorithm can be used to schedule meetings based on availability

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, scheduling, greedy

**Given:**

A dictionary of availabilities and meeting times, where

key: person's name

value: [start time(inclusive), end time(exclusive), duration]

Start time & end time are denoted by integer >= 0
Duration denoted by integer >= 1

**How do you generate a schedule of these meetings?**

Meetings cannot be split up. A schedule can be formed, guaranteed.
When more than 1 meeting can be given the same slot, keep the name order in the dict.

Sample input:

`{ John: [1,3,2],  Mary: [0,4,1],  Peter: [2,6,2],  Susan: [3,4,1] }`

Sample output:

`[Mary, John, John, Susan, Peter, Peter]`

I thought of using some kind of greedy algorithm, sorting by earliest availability end time to fill the schedule. But the availability interval can be greater than actual the meeting duration. I'm getting stuck on how to handle that.

Comment: The usual candidates like integer-programming and constraint-programming will probably perform *really well*. Especially integer-programming. It also has the advantages of supporting optimization (e.g. also optimizing *earliness*) and proving optimality. A very simple and very powerful approach would be just to provide one boolean decision-variable for each possible starting-point for each person. Then you add *conflicts* a-priori (you can precompute them). This is a nice form for such solvers (and could even be improved through some more advanced algorithmic graph-theory).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OptaPlanner's meeting scheduling example ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLK2-4IGtWY&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns)), conference scheduling example or employee rostering quickstart. The first matches your requirements best, and the latter two show how to add an availability constraint.

They all use a Greedy algorithm (First Fit) to initialize a good starting solution and then a Local Search (Late Acceptance) to improve that starting solution. Both algorithms are explained in [the documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html).

[image]